# How to display fixed background image behind all other content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background

I'm trying to add a fixed background image and show behind normal text content from another div. Image needs to be fixed, so that the rest of the content of the page can be scrolled and full image stays visible. The background image needs to be in a separate div (*that's how the HTML is currently structured and I can't change it*).
For some unknown reason, the background image keeps covering all content. How do I make it show behind content?

**Side notes:**

1. I have Bootstrap 5.0.1 loaded, but Bootstrap is not at fault here.
2. I tried playing around with `z-index` but with no success.

Code snippet:

```css
#backgroundImage {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
image-orientation: from-image;
background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/AD3MbBi.jpeg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left;
background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="container">
    <div id="backgroundImage"></div>
    <div class="buttons text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">some button</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row p-2 ontop">
    <p>asdasdasdads sdfsfsdfsd fsdfsd fsd</p>
    <p>fsdfdsf ssdf sdfsd fwefwefwe ewefwewe</p>
    <p>fsdfdsf ergerger gerg ergwrwewe</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Original fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6bytes/vsrawpu8/27/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided your text element has a higher z-index, you can place a negative z-index on your element with the position fixed and it will work.

***MDN:*** *The z-index CSS property sets the z-order of a **positioned** element and its descendants or flex items. Overlapping elements with a larger z-index cover those with a smaller one.*

```css
#backgroundImage {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
image-orientation: from-image;
background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/AD3MbBi.jpeg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left;
background-size: contain;
z-index: -1;
}

.row {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="container">
    <div id="backgroundImage"></div>
    <div class="buttons text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">some button</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row p-2 ontop">
    <p>asdasdasdads sdfsfsdfsd fsdfsd fsd</p>
    <p>fsdfdsf ssdf sdfsd fwefwefwe ewefwewe</p>
    <p>fsdfdsf ergerger gerg ergwrwewe</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
    <p>fsdfdsfw efwefwe fwefwe fweewwefwefwef</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
#backgroundImage {
            
            background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/AD3MbBi.jpeg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }


 <div id="backgroundImage">
       ...All you content
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't redo HTML like that. I have to stick with current HTML structure :(

Comment: Note also that background-attachment: fixed does not work as expected on IOS.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you're img container is in a parent div (and the z-index does not work). If you want to place it behind your text, try to place it at the same level or at a higher-level in the DOM and then play with z-index.